# How to stop icmpv6 neighbor advertisement storm

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openvswitch

I have two virtual machines, on each VM, I have two interfaces (**enp0s3**, **enp0s8**). Each interface belongs to different subnet.

On each VM I have created an OVS bridge **br0**, and on **br0**, I have created a VXLAN port with a remote IP pointing at **enp0s3** on the other VM.

The problem is when I connect **enp0s8** to **br0**, I have an icmpv6 neighbor advertisement storm on **enp0s3**, and when I delete **enp0s8** port on **br0** the broadcast immediately stops.

How can I stop the icmpv6 neighbor advertisement excessive broadcast? Any insight or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is getting created, one way to overcome this problem is to enable STP protocol which dynamically removes loops from the network:

ovs-vsctl set bridge  stp_enable=true